# tsc still throw an error after validating property's existing

Tags: typescript

`typescript` version is `3.1.1`

Here is my code:

```
interface IMessage<Body> {
  type?: string;
  body?: Body;
}

interface ICreateUserParameter {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

function validateMessage<Body>(message: IMessage<Body>): boolean {
  if (!message.type) {
    console.error('message.type is required');
    return false;
  }
  if (!message.body) {
    console.error('message.body is required');
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

function main(message: IMessage<ICreateUserParameter>) {
  if (!validateMessage<ICreateUserParameter>(message)) {
    return;
  }

  createUser(message.body);  // tsc throw an error here
}

function createUser(body: ICreateUserParameter) {
  return body;
}

export { main };
```

I do some validations for `message`. I think if the `message` is valid, which means the code flow will go to invoke `createUser` method, the `message.body` should be existed.

But `tsc` give me an error:

```
[ts]
Argument of type 'ICreateUserParameter | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ICreateUserParameter'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'ICreateUserParameter'.
```

How can I solve this? thanks.

Comment: Try changing `body?: Body;` to `body?: ICreateUserParameter;` in the IMessage interface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Narrowing (the automatic updating of the type of a variable after you test it) doesn't go through functions.  The best you can do in this case is probably to use a [user-defined type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards):

```
interface ICompleteMessage<Body> { 
  type: string;
  body: Body;
}

function validateMessage<Body>(message: IMessage<Body>): message is ICompleteMessage<Body> {
  // ...
}
```